# Texture painting only working in UV/Image editor

Tags: 3d-view, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I'm a bit new to blender and I have had a reoccurring issue with the texture painting either not effecting the 3d view model in a productive manner(painting over a million times with little effect) or not working at all while being fully functional in the UV/Image Editor. Am I missing a setting?

Comment: Have you UV unwrapped your object by going into edit mode, select all vertices and use the 'u' key  -> unwrap?

Comment: Yes, Its unwrapped and I can even paint the 3d model from the UV/Image editor, just not on the 3d view itself.

Comment: there is a panel named 'slots' below the tools when you enter texture paint mode, you want to have a look at this maybe.

Comment: You nailed it Yvain! I would have never thought to look in "Slots" for the Painting Mode. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem. I know it's been 3 years, so I guess you find a way to fix this, but if someone has the same issue, try deactivating the *Backface Culling* option in the brush options.

[image]

Comment: And along similar lines, perhaps you've just got your normals inverted and need to just flip the normals. That was my problem, but this answer helped me spot it.